# BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...) always returns null as Bitmap

Tags: android

I want to load Bitmap from Url in a background thread. My method looks like below.

```
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromURL(String url,int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        InputStream is=null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Rect rect = new Rect(-1, -1, -1, -1);
        Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,rect, options);
        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,rect, options);
        return bmp2;
    }
```

I always get bmp1 and bmp2 as null. why?

Comment: Are you getting a correct value in the variable __response__?

Comment: actually the url is "http://something.jpg" and I can't check if I get the proper value in response variable. can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

maybe check if input stream is null, to se whether bad bitmap code or getting input stream code. 
maybe Rect should have proper dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

you are decoding the stream with option to decode bounds so obviously the bitmap out put will be null, and then you are trying to decode bitmap from the same stream, which was already used in the first decoding. You can try reading the stream to byte array buffer and then wrap bytearrayInputstreams, remember to create new streams for each decoding

Comment: can you please explain by example